# Group checkboxes for entities in a Symfony form

Tags: symfony

How can I group checkboxes for entities in Symfony forms?

```
->add(
    'products',
    EntityType::class,
    [
        'class' => Product::class,
        'choice_label' => 'titel',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
    ]
)
```

Im my domain model a `Product` belongs to exactly one `ProductFamily`. Every `ProductFamily` belongs to exactly one `ProductSuperFamily`. In my form the `Product` checkboxes should be grouped like this:

```
Product Super Family 1
    Product Family 1
        [ ] Product 1
        [ ] Product 2
    Product Family 2
        [ ] Product 3
    Product Family 3
        [ ] Product 4
        [ ] Product 5
Product Super Family 2
    Product Family 4
        [ ] Product 6
        [ ] Product 7
        [ ] Product 8
    Product Family 5
        [ ] Product 9
Product Super Family 3
    Product Family 6
        [ ] Product 10
        [ ] Product 11
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed by the choice type, you must use [the `group_by` option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by):

```
'group_by' => function(Product $product) {
    return $product->getFamily()->getLabel()
},
```

Comment: Does `group_by` help me with the additional grouping by `SuperFamily`?

Comment: Perhaps you could try.

Comment: If the 'expanded' flag is set true, then all groups are being flatten out,
which is documented.

However, solutions to this have been shared yet; [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5489) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011427/symfony2-form-checkbox-grouped-expanded-and-multiple-choice).