# Symfony 3 Form ChoiceType: Group checkboxes for bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a big form created with Symfony and one doctrine field with many (~ 30) choices. For the choices I use the ChoiceType. The choices are added as an array:

```
'tv' => [ # TV- & RADIO-PRODUKTION
    'cb one' => 1,
    'cb two' => 2,
    'cb three' => 3,
],
'av' => [ # AV-Produktion
    'cb four' => 4,
    'cb five' => 5,
    'cb six' => 6,
],

...
```

Form field:

```
->add('productionType', ChoiceType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'label' => 'Produktionstyp',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices' => $options['production_type_choices'],
]);
```

How can I render the choices of the form field in twig including the "groupes" in the array ('tv' & 'av')?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224662/group-checkboxes-for-entities-in-a-symfony-form

Comment: The choice values are not entities!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#grouping-options

Comment: Yes, that only works if the field is rendered as `select` field. I need it as checkboxes